# Can't ping VirtualBox guest IP, but can access services via port forwarding

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have VirtualBox set up with two network interfaces (one NAT and one host-only). I've been using this VM to do web development for a long time. Recently upon booting it up, I'm no longer able to ping the VM via the IP address of the network adaptor. However, I can still access the VM via port forwarding.

Example: I used to access it by doing `ssh root@[ip-address-of-vm]`, but that no longer works. However, since I have set up forwarding for port 22 on the guest to port 2222 on the host, I can still do `ssh root@localhost:2222` and access the VM that way.

This tells me that the network adaptors "work", since I can still access the VM. But suddenly I can't access them directly via their own IP. I'm running Ubuntu on the host and I've tried disabling UFW in case it was a firewall issue, but no change. The guest is running Debian, if that matters.

I haven't changed anything with the VM config. I'm guessing it may have something to do with having run updates and had something change out from underneath me (e.g. updated to a new version of virtualbox when I did `apt dist-upgrade`).

I'm a bit stumped. Any suggestions for things to try?

Comment: Are you trying to access the address assigned to the NAT-mode interface or to the host-only interface?

Comment: I've tried both available IP addresses (10.0.2.15, which I think is NAT, and 172.28.128.3, which I think is the host-only). Neither can be pinged. Normally I would use 172.28.128.3 to access the VM (e.g. ssh root@172.28.128.3).

Comment: Does the host-only interface have a correct IP address assigned on the host itself? That is, does Ubuntu also have an 172.28.128.x address on `vboxnet0`? Is the vboxnet0 interface even up? (It is normal that the NAT address won't work, as VirtualBox's "NAT" is invisible to the host system, which is why 'host-only' mode exists in the first place, and also why NAT-mode needs to have the port-forwarding feature...)

Comment: No, there is no vboxnet0 interface, nor a 172.28.128.x address on the host. Not sure if there was one before I started having this problem.

Comment: There should have been one; it's how the host talks to VirtualBox's "host-only" network.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Not sure how to get it back, but it gives me something to read up on. While there is no vboxnet0 interface when I do ifconfig, I notice that it does get listed if I do `vboxmanage list hostonlyifs`. However, the listing says `Status: Down`. I assume that's the heart of the issue, but not sure how to rectify it.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your advice led me to try some new search terms and I found this post: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1460750

After reading the thread, I tried doing `sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 172.28.128.5`. Once I did that, ifconfig shows the vboxnet0 interface again, and `vboxmanage list hostonlyifs` shows the status as "Up". I can now connect to the interface again as normal.

Not sure how the interface got destroyed, but at least now I know how to get it back.

Comment: ifconfig hides interfaces that are 'down' unless you use the `-a` option. That doesn't mean they're not there. (ifconfig on Linux also has many other issues. Just don't use ifconfig on Linux. Use `ip link` or `ip addr`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is that the "Host-only" network interface `vboxnet0` on the host system lost its IP configuration for some reason – or was never configured successfully in the first place.

Normally VirtualBox itself creates this virtual interface on the host OS, brings it 'up', and assigns it an IP address from the host-only subnet. (I'm not sure if this is supposed to happen on boot, but I think it's only done when you start VirtualBox for the first time after reboot.)

---

Meanwhile, it is normal that the "NAT" network is not reachable, because VirtualBox NAT isn't actually connected to the host's network stack (it does not use Linux built-in NAT) – the whole 10.0.2.x network is emulated by the VirtualBox service, and the host OS itself is completely unaware of its existence.

Comment: For anyone looking for the details of how this was fixed, basically I had to reconfigure the vboxnet0 interface by doing `sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 172.28.128.5`, see more details in comments below original question.